# Subversion Subclipse does not work with Apache Commons

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I just installed subclipse in Eclipse to checkout:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/validator/trunk/

But this fails with the following error message:

```
Repository has been moved
svn: Repository moved permanently to '/viewvc/commons/proper/validator/trunk/'; please relocate
```

I do not understand this error. As the URL(as can be seen above) is exactly like this? Does anyone know what could be the cause for this error?

Thank you very much
Markuis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) web view as your SVN URL in Eclipse.  It is a human readable view, not an SVN-readable view.

From the Commons Validator [Source Repository page](http://commons.apache.org/validator/source-repository.html), the current Commons Validator SVN URL is:

```
svn:http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/validator/trunk/
```

(You *can* access the true SVN in a web browser, but the rendering is simpler than ViewVC provides: [ViewVC](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/validator/trunk/) vs [raw SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/validator/trunk/))

Comment: Thanks very much. Well for a newbie programming is sometimes so frustrating... Nothing works;-) I would have never come to the idea that there are two urls. Thanks!! (Well and the error message above is also typically geeky, why does this not state that I need to use another url...)